# Embedded YouTube video not working in Ionic3 lazy-loaded page

Tags: ionic-framework, youtube, ionic3

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video through their `iframe API` in Ionic 3 app on a lazy-loaded page.

**sample.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({
  name: 'samplePage',
  segment: 'sample'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'page-sample',
  templateUrl: 'sample.html'
})
export class SamplePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

**sample.module.ts**

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import { SamplePage } from './sample';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SamplePage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(SamplePage)
    ],
    exports: [
        SamplePage
    ]
})
export class SamplePageModule {
}
```

**sample.html**

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID" frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I was expecting that this YouTube video will work in all the browsers but this is random. 
The video is not working on Chrome browser but when I open the developer mode or change the screen size it works.

This is only happening when I'm adding it to a lazy loaded page using `@IonicPage()` annotation but when I remove this annotation and use the page normally, that works fine everywhere.

Comment: what dou want to do exact